# Array mesh with emission node not working

Tags: modifiers, emission

What details do you want to see? Read my question and then read the answer. What needs to be added? I don't get it?????
Please elaborate this in detail.

**Question is useful and is being answered properly....**

I am trying to array a mesh that has emission node on it.
The issue I am facing is that the object that is duplicated does not show any emission.

Is it possible to array a mesh that has emission and if yes how to do it?

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot below the mesh on the right side does not give "light"
While the parent one on the left does.

Comment: It's often helpful and even necessary to attach an example blend file, especially for troubleshooting like in this case

Comment: Light is coming from a lamp object, not the emission shader

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Indirect light is coming from an mesh object not a lamp object

Comment: works, see my answer. if yours doesn't work, provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Hi @cecevo It is unclear what the issue is from the information you've provided. Modifiers have little effects over shaders, other than possibly changing texture coordinates. You clipped the important part of your material that would show texture coordinates. EEVEE doesn't support emission from objects yet you don't mention what render engine you are using. You also commented that you accidentally deleted something from your node tree and after restoring it worked again, so I'm not sure this question can be useful as it stands. Both your edits added nothing to make the issue clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emission on an arrayed object works, look here:

Cycles render:

[image]

Eevee render:

[image]

Comment: When preparing the blend file to upload I mistakenly deleted my colorramp and then it worked. There must be something with my node setup thats not good.

Thanks BTW for your time and afford helping me out.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Did you rendered on Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: this was made in cycles (the render) but it works on eevee too

Comment: ok Thanks. 
I am still figuring out how to get the light reflect from objects in EEVEE coz I don't get the same result as you. That's why I asked you :-)

Comment: i updated my answer with an eevee render...of course, the light effect by the emission looks much better in cycles...

Comment: you have to turn on screen space reflections...and then a material with metallic high (near 1) and roughness low (near 0)

Comment: Have to use cycles coz EEVEE does not have path tracing I guess. The indirect light works a lot better in Cycles then in EEVEE not matter what settings. And Baking it in EEVEE does work but takes way to much time.... Thanks for all the time and info you gave me @Chris preciate it much!!